# Ignoring newline with fgets() when reading in a file

Tags: c, fgets

Hi I am currently trying my hand at C programming and am a bit stuck. I am trying to read in a .txt file line by line and process each line separately using fgets() but I need to ignore the newline in the file as it is affecting the output of my code. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance :)

```
static void Test ()
{

    int bufferLength;
    char* buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

    FILE *file = fopen("testing.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file)) {
        FILE *file2 = fopen("tester.txt", "w");
        fprintf(file2, "%s", buffer);
        fclose(file2);
        FILE *file3 = fopen("tester.txt", "r");
        process(file3);
        fclose(file3);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: I see nowhere the initialization of `bufferLength`. This implies that the `malloc` function will fail.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Well, it might fail, or it might not. The application is requesting a random amount of memory, so if one would add a check for `buffer == NULL`, this should "work" and read lines into a buffer of random size (not that such a behavior would be useful in any way).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```

inside of the `while` loop, right after going into the loop body.

Note, that `bufferLength` isn´t initialized by any value and as it is an object of `auto`matic storage duration it will contain a garbage value. Using `bufferLength` this way is undefined behavior.

Initialize `bufferLength` to any reasonable buffer length, for example:

```
int bufferLength = 20;
```

---

This is what it shall look like:

```
static void Test ()
{

    int bufferLength = 20;
    char* buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

    FILE *file = fopen("testing.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file)) {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;        // <-- here.
        FILE *file2 = fopen("tester.txt", "w");
        fprintf(file2, "%s", buffer);
        fclose(file2);
        FILE *file3 = fopen("tester.txt", "r");
        process(file3);
        fclose(file3);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Side note: The function `strcspn()` is defined in the header of `string.h`. You need to `#include` it in order to use it.

Credit goes to [@Tim Cas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485088/tim-%c4%8cas), from which I learned this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/12139179).